# Unable to resolve 'No module named Appium' error

Tags: python, eclipse, appium, browserstack

I am setting up my environment for automation using browserstack. I tried to implement the following code based on their instructions:

```
from Appium import webdriver
enter code here`from Appium.webdriver.common.mobileby import MobileBy
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

userName = "cathytest1"
accessKey = "5u8P4kxrPdw3bCDPtyCU"

desired_caps = {
    "build": "Python Android",
    "device": "Samsung Galaxy S8 Plus",
    "app": "bs://fa77cdc35c9dea891b543c3ab6bf2897b300e229"
}

driver = webdriver.Remote("http://" + userName + ":" + accessKey + "@hub- 
cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub", desired_caps)

search_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((MobileBy.ACCESSIBILITY_ID, "Search 
Wikipedia"))
)
search_element.click()

search_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((MobileBy.ID, 
"org.wikipedia.alpha:id/search_src_text"))
)
search_input.send_keys("BrowserStack")
time.sleep(5)

search_results = 
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("android.widget.TextView")
assert(len(search_results) > 0)

driver.quit()
```

But I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/C:\EclipseWorkspaces\csse120/Browserstack/src/Sample/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Appium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Appium'
```

I have already set up Appium in my Eclipse IDE via Marketplace but still, the issue isn't resolved.

Comment: As far as I know, the marketplace appium would be some kind of plugin, you will have to install appium on your machine, that should resolve the issue.

Comment: Any error if you do `python -c 'from Appium import webdriver'` in shell?

Comment: @atline what does the above code will do? I have not done this before

Comment: Just same as you open python in bash terminal, and type `from Appium import webdriver`, this just to narrow your issue. As seems you run code in IDE?

Comment: @atline yes, I run the code in Eclipse IDE. And when I do so, I encounter the error above.

Comment: Output of `python -c 'import os; print(os.__file__)'`?

Comment: @atline this is the output:
cathy0320:~ Cathy$ python -c 'from Appium import webdriver'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Appium'
cathy0320:~ Cathy$

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade to Python 3 and then install the Appium. I have faced the same issue and it get solved once updated to Python 3.

1. Uninstall Python 2.7
2. Install Python 3 & above (latest: Python 3.7.4 )
3. upgrade the pip
4. Install Appium client (> pip install appium-python-client)
5. Then run the script

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have appium installed? If no, install it via pip: `pip install Appium-Python-Client` and then try to replace `Appium` with `appium` in your code. In my system, it worked

Comment: You have to run pip as an administrator; if you have no pip, I guess, you can download and install it from python.org

Comment: hi @Kolay.Ne I have already installed pip:

Last login: Tue Apr 30 07:41:39 on console
cathy0320:~ Cathy$ pip install Appium-Python-Client
Requirement already satisfied: Appium-Python-Client in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (0.36)
Requirement already satisfied: selenium>=3.14.1 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from Appium-Python-Client) (3.141.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from selenium>=3.14.1->Appium-Python-Client) (1.24)
cathy0320:~ Cathy$

Comment: In python console run `import appium`. Everything in lowcase! What is the output?

Comment: I have replaced 'Appium' to 'appium' already, but seems not fixed

Comment: Could you, please, check if the path to the apium module in your os.path?

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably because of you are using virtual environment. To resolve this issue open cmd. In cmd type cd <path\project.venv>(replace this path with your project directory and .venv with you virtual environment name. If you didn't give virtual environment name it is most likely be .venv). Now hit enter.
After that type the command .\Scripts\activate (make sure that .venv is before the path in prompt (.venv) in my case (.venv) C:\Users\vibho\Documents\Pro\python\AI.venv>). Now just simply type
pip install  Appium. This will install Appium in your virtual environment.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing **from Appium import webdriver** with **import apium**.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34755291)